# spring-integration parallel split-route-aggregate flow fails due to one-way MessageHandler

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I want to process a list of items in parallel by splitting them, routing each item to their appropriate gateway and aggregating the results. However, my application does not start, I get the following error:

```
BeanCreationException: The 'currentComponent' ... is a one-way 'MessageHandler' 
and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'. 
This is the end of the integration flow.
```

This is a sample flow definition which illustrates the behaviour:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow parallelSplitRouteAggregateFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundGateway("/trigger"))
            .handle(message -> Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
            .split()
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .<Integer, Boolean>route(o -> o % 2 == 0, m -> m
                    .subFlowMapping(true, oddFlow())
                    .subFlowMapping(false, evenFlow()))
            .aggregate()
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow oddFlow() {
    return flow -> flow.<Integer>handle((payload, headers) -> "odd");
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow evenFlow() {
    return flow -> flow.<Integer>handle((payload, headers) -> "even");
}
```

I have seen [Error 'is a one-way 'MessageHandler' for spring-integration aggregator DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725701/error-is-a-one-way-messagehandler-for-spring-integration-aggregator-dsl), but the solution there does not apply here, I am not logging in a handle() method.
I also tried to add .defaultOutputToParentFlow() to the mappingDefinition because the cafe example uses it, but that makes no difference either.

I should mention that this is spring-integration 5.0.4 with spring-boot 2.0.1 release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is here:

```
.handle(message -> Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
```

if you would use an inline implementation, it would look like:

```
.handle(new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        }
})
```

Pay attention to the `void` return type. Since there is nothing to return, therefore there is nothing to send downstream - `is a one-way 'MessageHandler'`.

To fix your problem you need to do this:

```
 .handle((p, h) -> Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
.handle(new GenericHandler<Object>() {

        @Override
        public Object handle(Object p, Map<String, Object> h) {
            return Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        }
})
```

Actually my IDEA say me for your variant like:

[image]

That gives me some hint that I'm doing something wrong.

**UPDATE**

The working code:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow parallelSplitRouteAggregateFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundGateway("/trigger"))
            .handle((p, h) -> Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
            .split()
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .<Integer, Boolean>route(o -> o % 2 == 0, m -> m
                    .subFlowMapping(true, sf -> sf.gateway(oddFlow()))
                    .subFlowMapping(false, sf -> sf.gateway(evenFlow())))
            .aggregate()
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow oddFlow() {
    return flow -> flow.<Integer>handle((payload, headers) -> "odd");
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow evenFlow() {
    return flow -> flow.<Integer>handle((payload, headers) -> "even");
}
```

Comment: But it still won't work because the router is a one-way component. The odd/even flows need to send to the aggregator input channel in a separate flow. Right?

Comment: That's not true, Gary. See our `RouterTests`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/routers/RouterTests.java#L581

Comment: Hmmm - it blew up for me until I broke out the aggregate() `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: The 'currentComponent' (org.springframework.integration.router.MethodInvokingRouter@41de5768) is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'. This is the end of the integration flow.`. The difference is his router hands off to another flow; it's not an inline subflow.

Comment: Oh! That :-)! Well, then there is just no need in `@Bean` on those sub-flows

Comment: If I define the subflow in-place as in
`.subFlowMapping("odd", f -> f.<Integer>handle((payload, headers) -> "odd"))` I do not have to define an aggregation channel. Why is that, what is the difference between an inline flow and another flow? 
Can I avoid aggregating outside the main flow? - I would rather have split and aggregate in one flow definition.

Comment: As I said: you can declare those sub-flows externally, but they must not be as `@Bean`s. The `@Bean` makes it a fully blown `IntegrationFlow`, so it becomes essentially not as a `sub-flow`. It's not a light version any more.

Comment: If you can't remove `@Bean` from there since you may use it as a standalone flow, you should consider to `.gateway()` to them: `.subFlowMapping(true, sf -> sf.gateway(oddFlow()))`

Comment: See an `UPDATE` in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow parallelSplitRouteAggregateFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundGateway("/trigger"))
            .handle((p, h) -> Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
            .split()
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .<Integer, Boolean>route(o -> o % 2 == 0, m -> m
                    .subFlowMapping(true, oddFlow())
                    .subFlowMapping(false, evenFlow()))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow oddFlow() {
    return flow -> flow.<Integer>handle((payload, headers) -> "odd")
            .channel("agg.input");
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow evenFlow() {
    return flow -> flow.<Integer>handle((payload, headers) -> "even")
        .channel("agg.input");
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow agg() {
    return f -> f.aggregate();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to "distribute" messages over several "workers", and have the messages back at a join point, there's the method `.scatterGather(...)`. Deemingly, it wraps up the `.route(...)` functionality in a way more suitable to be used within the IntegrationFlow's domain.

It is showed in the following example:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow evenOddFlows() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/trigger"))
                .handle((payload,headers)->Arrays.asList(1,2,3))
                .split()
                .scatterGather(r->r.applySequence(true)
                .recipientFlow(m->(int)m.getPayload()%2==0, evenFlow-> evenFlow.log(m->"Even flow with payload: "+m.getPayload()).<Integer,Integer>transform(h-> h+50)
                        .handle((payload,headers)->(int)payload+50).log(m->"At Even flow end with payload: "+m.getPayload())
                        .handle((payload,headers)->payload) /* This .handle(...) doesn't do a real job.
* Instead, it is to patch something that at least I regard as a bug.
* Having not the .handle(...) would leave the .log(...) at the end of the flow.
* After crossing a .log(...) if right at the flow's end, the response message doesn't arrive back the parent flow (hence my aprising there is a bug).
* With the "appended" .handle(...) afterwards, avoid the .log(...) being the last one in the flow, as well as tests show the message is sent away where the parent flow receives it.
*/
                        )
                        .recipientFlow(m->(int)m.getPayload()%2!=0, oddFlow-> oddFlow.log(m->"Odd flow with payload: "+m.getPayload()).<Integer,Integer>transform(h-> h+10)
                        .handle((payload,headers)->(int)payload+10).log(m->"At Odd flow end with payload: "+m.getPayload())
                        .handle((payload,headers)->payload) // This .handle(...) I needed as a patch because otherwise the .log(...) being the last one in the subflow swallowed the message
                        )
                        )
                        .aggregate()
                        .get()
                ;
    }
```

```
curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/trigger
```

Curl outputs:

```
[[21],[102],[23]]
```

Logs:

```
2019-05-17 16:19:11.061  INFO 10148 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : Odd flow with payload: 1
2019-05-17 16:19:11.061  INFO 10148 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : At Odd flow end with payload: 21
2019-05-17 16:19:11.061  INFO 10148 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : Even flow with payload: 2
2019-05-17 16:19:11.061  INFO 10148 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : At Even flow end with payload: 102
2019-05-17 16:19:11.061  INFO 10148 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : Odd flow with payload: 3
2019-05-17 16:19:11.061  INFO 10148 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : At Odd flow end with payload: 23
```